# Why is it runway "1" instead of "01" in America?

Tags: faa-regulations, runways, airport-markings, icao-sarps

In the case of a runway with a magnetic heading of 10° in America the runway number ("1") isn't hugely distinguishable from the runway centreline IMHO, (for example see [Washington Airport](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@38.8472657,-77.0354146,1970m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en) and [San Francisco Airport](https://www.google.com/maps/@37.6092949,-122.3805451,721m/data=!3m1!1e3)).

Is there a reason why the USA doesn't add the leading zero like the EU (example [Brussels Airport](https://www.google.com/maps/@50.8878195,4.4917621,18z/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en-gb) and [RAF Waddington](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@53.154703,-0.5312034,333m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en))?

Does the ICAO make any recommendations about this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Indeed USA deviates from ICAO:

> 5.2.2.4 Zeros are not used to precede single-digit runway markings. An optional configuration of the numeral 1 is available to designate a runway 1 and to prevent confusion with the runway centerline.

Source: [USA AIP - GEN 1.7 Differences From ICAO SARPs](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aip_html/part1_gen_section_1.7.html)

5.2.2.4 in ICAO SARPs Annex 14 (Aerodromes) is as follows (emphasis mine):

> 5.2.2.4 A runway designation marking shall consist of a **two-digit number** and on parallel runways shall be supplemented with a letter. On a single runway, dual parallel runways and triple parallel runways the two-digit number shall be the whole number nearest the one-tenth of the magnetic North when viewed from the direction of approach. On four or more parallel runways, one set of adjacent runways shall be numbered to the nearest one-tenth magnetic azimuth and the other set of adjacent runways numbered to the next nearest one-tenth of the magnetic azimuth. When the above rule would give a **single digit number, it shall be preceded by a zero.**

*Shall* in ICAO legalese denotes a standard.

The aforementioned optional configuration for "1" covers your concern regarding the centerline:

> [image]
>
> The numeral "1", when used alone, contains a horizontal stroke, as shown, to differentiate it from the runway centerline marking.

Source: [FAA AC 150/5340-1](https://www.faa.gov/airports/resources/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.current/documentnumber/150_5340-1)

The rationale is not in the AIP; it's not always given. Deviations from SARPs are also very common, that's why there's an AIP section dedicated to them.

Comment: But the question is, *why* did the US choose to change the standard?

Comment: @RayButterworth: Who said USA changed it? More like kept doing what they were doing before the SARPs were written down. Check the linked list of differences, and add a dollar value to each. Fully adhering is super expensive -- especially for a country with a big aviation sector like USA -- and not always really beneficial (if it ain't broke...).

Comment: @RayButterworth it’s actually a two part question, why (if known) and what does ICAO say. The first half may be unanswerable, but this does a very good job of answering the second half in my opinion.